# A quasilinear PDE and its characteristic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the equation
$$(x+y)uu_x + (x-y)uu_y = x^2 + y^2$$
with the initial condition $u(x, 2x) = 0$. I managed to write down the characteristic
$$\frac{dx}{(x+y)u} = \frac{dy}{(x-y)u} = \frac{du}{x^2 + y^2}.$$
After some manipulations on the equation
$$\frac{dx}{(x+y)u} = \frac{dy}{(x-y)u},$$
I got
$$x^2-2xy-y^2 = c_1$$
for some constant $c_1$.

However, I couldn't manage to derive anything about $c_2$, the other constant which will show up in the solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Can you think about multipliers?

$\frac{xdx-ydy}{x^2u+xyu-xyu+y^2u} = \frac{du}{x^2 + y^2}$

$\implies xdx-ydy=udu$

$\implies \frac{1}{2}d(x^2-y^2-u^2)=0$

$\implies x^2-y^2-u^2=C$

Comment: It seems to me that I miss a lot today, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness i want to add the general solution of the PDE:

$$u\! \left(x,y\right)\mapsto-\sqrt{2 x y+f_{1}\! \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^{2}+2 x y+y^{2}}}\right)}$$

For the initial condition $u(x,2x)=0$ we get the equation $4x^{2}+f_{1}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7 \sqrt{x^{2}}}\right)=0$ with the solution

$$f_{1} (x)\mapsto -\frac{4}{7\cdot x^{2}}$$

and hence we get the final solution

$$u(x,y)\mapsto-\frac{\sqrt{28 \left(x+2 y\right) \left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)}}{7}$$